# Google Apps Scripts Idle time

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently using Google Apps Scripts to create a Drive Addon, and I noticed that if I leave a page idle for some time, the script functionality no longer executes (e.g. calls to google.script.run -- frontend-only stuff still works as expected)

I'm wondering if there is an idle timeout for apps script and if so, what kinds of techniques should I use to handle it cleanly?

Thanks!

Comment: You should give more details... what service are you using?  Html service?  what does the script do? What code stops working?  This is too vague to answer...

Comment: Thanks for the response Serge. I've managed to isolate the problem to having something to do with the Cache service provided by Apps Script. I wasn't aware that there was an expiry time on cache objects and have set it now to the maximum 6 hours. Does anyone know what the default value for the expiration is? I can't seem to find it in the docs.  EDIT - Ha, found it right after typing this response. "The default expiration is 600 seconds (10 minutes)." -- Hope this helps someone else who might encounter a similar issue.

Comment: Right, 10 minutes indeed.May be you should write this as an "own answer" when you can to improve visibility.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to isolate the problem to having something to do with the Cache service provided by Apps Script. I wasn't aware that there was an expiry time on cache objects and have set it now to the maximum 6 hours. The default expiration is 600 seconds (10 minutes).